# Book recommendation on Discrete Geometry

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, discrete-geometry

I have started studying discrete geometry. And I need some good suggestions on discrete geometry books. I am looking for something rigorous with a lot of solved examples (if possible).
Some books that I am following right now are

1. Lectures on Discrete and Polyhedral Geometry by Igor Pak (found it a little bit advanced)
2. Lectures on Discrete Geometry Textbook by Jiří Matoušek.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should ask your instructor for some recommendations.

Comment: You are going to need the basics of abstract algebra as well (which is true of just about any graduate-level math course).

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks. Could you suggest some introductory books for the same.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you for the comment. Our instructor suggested Lectures on Discrete and Polyhedral Geometry  by IgorPak. It starts with helly's theorem without any other introduction ( and I find it difficult to understand since I have no proper background). And I'm getting confused about how to prove any problems using any specific theorem. So I need a more introductory book that has some problems and solutions.

Comment: Alas, no. The book I learned it from is not one I would recommend (if you could even find it), and I never found out what the standard texts were.

Comment: @PaulSinclair... I am doomed then....

Comment: I wouldn't go that far. Pretty much any intro to abstract algebra book will have the information you need. Indeed, It may even been covered adequately in the Discrete Geometry book intro chapters. You mostly need to understand Groups. What they are and basic properties/constructions - particularly quotient groups. Again, this is needed for pretty much any grad math course. Algebras, fields, and modules may also be useful, but not as much as groups. Only the basics - you are unlikely to need Sylow theorems or Galois theory.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks. I do have idea ( I have studied them during linear algebra courses) about algebraic structure.

Comment: I think I have to study about topology also. We have started with Helly's theorem and it has a lot of proofs that requires the idea about closed segments and open segments, compactness and all.

Comment: As it is phrased right now, this question is asking for personal advice.  It is very likely that you could rephrase this question so that it is of more general interest, and not so narrowly focused on your situation.  However, until those edits are made, this question is off-topic here.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks for the suggestion. I have edited my question. Please have a look and share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Try Matthias Beck, Sinai Robins: *Computing the Continuous Discretely.* This is an extremely well-written book for undergraduates.